# Point System Storage

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm having trouble picking between an array, arraylist, or a list for one of the features of this small game I'm designing in Java. I'm not limited to those three, those are just the ones I know of.

The feature is that the player unlocks a certain text/button whenever they reach that certain amount of points. So, what I would like to store a "list" that contains a collection of two points. One point that gives the required point amount, and the second point is either a string or something else that would be unlocked.

I was leaning towards just a plain old 2-d array for this but decided to post it here so I could get more opinions.

Comment: It *sounds* like what you want is an ordered map.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of "unlocks", maybe consider using a enum

Answer (score 3):

If the two values are linked I would use a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to store the values. This allows you to easily access the corresponding value. Example: (Assuming the points that are linked to the achievement are `int`'s and the achievement is a `String`)

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> hashmap = new HashMap<>(); 
 assignments.put(18, "New Achievement");
 //Etc
```

Where `18` is the number of points and `New Achievement` is the achievement the user has unlocked.

As chrylis said if the values are in continuous order a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html)would be a good choice to look into.

A good [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/navigableset-java-examples/) for the `NavigableMap`

Comment: In a case like this, a `NavigableMap` is probably more suitable since it lets you easily keep track of what comes next.

Comment: @chrylis That is an excellent point. I edited my answer to include it.

Comment: Oh wow, ok that sounds very useful. But @chrylis how is it easier to keep track of what comes next?

Comment: @Briehn Because a map that implements `NavigableMap` stores the pairs sorted by key, and since you seem to be storing a sequential set of items that are unlocked at point values, you get sort of a "timeline" of point values.

Comment: @GBlodgett Note that "sequential" doesn't necessarily mean *continuous*, and integers are sequential by definition.